# Can I use stripe's simple JS form with subscriptions?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a rails app that I'm trying to implement stripe on. I need subscriptions and I'd like to use the really simple JS form stripe provides but i'm not sure how to do it with subscriptions.

With the JS form (shown below), it seems I can't specify a plan or a way to know which plan was selected. Here's my view:

```
= form_tag subscriptions_path do
  %article
    %label.amount
      %span Plan: Basic, Amount: $5.00
  %script.stripe-button{"data-amount" => "500", "data-description" => "A month's subscription", "data-key" => Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key], src: "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"}
```

here's my create method in subscriptions controller:

```
  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: current_user.company.admin.email,
      plan:  '???'
      card:  params[:stripeToken]
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to subscriptions_path
  end
```

how do I know which plan was selected from the stripe form checkout.js

Comment: Have you got plans set up in Stripe, or just want to handle the price you send through?